# Finding a simple upper bound for the number of primes in $x, x+p_k\#, x+2p_k\#, \dots, x+(p_k\#-1)p_k\#$

Tags: prime-numbers, solution-verification, mobius-function, primorial

Let:

- $p_k$ be the $k$th prime.
- $p\#$ be the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) for $p$
- gcd$(a,b)$ the the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of $a$ and $b$
- $\mu(x)$ be the [möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function)
- $x$ be an integer such that $p_k < x < p_k\#$ and gcd$(x,p_k\#)=1$
- $X$ be the set: $x, x+p_k\#, x+2p_k\#, \dots, x+(p_k\#-1)p_k\#$

Does it follow that if $p_k > 300$:

There are less than $p_k\# - \left(\dfrac{1.99p_k}{\ln 2p_k}\right)\left(\dfrac{p_{k-1}\#}{2}\right)$ primes in $X$.

Here's my thinking:

(1) If $p_k > 300$, there are at least $\dfrac{1.99p_k}{\ln 2p_k}$ primes between $p_k$ and $2p_k$

> - From [Rosser & Schoenfeld (1962)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities), if $x \ge 17$:
>   $$\dfrac{x}{\ln x} < x < \dfrac{1.25506x}{\ln x}$$
> - $\pi(2x) - \pi(x) > \dfrac{2x(\ln x) - 1.25506(\ln 2x)}{(\ln x)(\ln 2x)} > \dfrac{(2x-1.25506)\ln x - 1.25506\ln 2}{(\ln x)(\ln 2x)} > \dfrac{2x - 1.25506}{\ln 2x} - 0.0871$
> - Since for $x \ge 300$, $\dfrac{x}{\ln 2x}$ is increasing:
>   $$\dfrac{2x - 1.25506}{\ln 2x} - 0.0871 > \dfrac{2x - 0.01x}{\ln 2x} = \dfrac{1.99x}{\ln 2x}$$

(2) Since $x, x+p_k\#, x+2p_k\#, \dots, x+(p_k\#-1)p_k\#$ forms a set of complete residue systems modulo each prime, it follows that the number of primes is equal to:

> $$p_k\# - \sum\limits_{\text{gcd}(i,p_k\#)=1\text{ and }i < p_k\#}\mu(i)\left\lfloor\frac{p_k\#}{i}\right\rfloor$$

(3) Then, the number of primes is less than:

> $$p_k\# - \sum\limits_{p_k < s < 2p_k}\left\lfloor\frac{p_k\#}{s}\right\rfloor + \sum\limits_{p_k < s,t < 2p_k\text{ and }s \ne t}\left\lfloor\frac{p_k\#}{st}\right\rfloor$$

(4) Which is less than:

> $$p_k\# - \left(\frac{1.99p_k}{\ln 2p_k}\right)\left(\frac{p_{k-1}\#}{2}\right)$$

Is this correct?  Is there a more straight forward way to show the same conclusion?  Is there are any holes in my argument that need to be demonstrated?